# Cannot read property 'params' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to edit data in database using fetch but it shows cannot read property 'params' of undefined error where i am fetching it will not get that id using this.props.match.params.id 
here is my **action**

```js
const reportsFetched = (reports,r_id) => {
    return {
        type: 'REPORTS_FETCHED',
        reports,
        r_id

    }
}

export const fetchReportsbyid = (r_id) => {
    return dispatch => {
         fetch(`http://localhost/aruna/getreportsbyid.php?r_id=${r_id}`).
            then(resp => resp.json()).
            then(data => dispatch(reportsFetched(data.reports)));    
        }
}
```

**my reducer file**

```js
    export default (state=reportsDefaultstate, action ) => {
    switch (action.type){
        case 'ADD_REPORT':
            return [
                ...state,
                action.reports
            ]
        case 'REPORTS_FETCHED':
        const index = state.findIndex(item => item.r_id === action.reports.r_id);
        if(index > -1){
           return state.map((item) => {
          if(item.r_id === action.reports.r_id) return action.reports
             return item
               })
           }else{
               return [...state]
           }
            
        case 'SET_REPORTS':
            return action.reports
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

my **listitem**

```js
const Reportlistitem = ({r_id, reg_date, reg_no, patient_name, gender, age, mobile_no , email_id , refer_by, test_request , report_status , total_amt, receipt_amt, bal_amt}) => (
    
    <div >
    <table>
    <tbody key={r_id}>            
    <tr>
    <td>{reg_date}</td>
    <td>{reg_no}</td>
    <td>{patient_name}</td>
    <td>{gender}</td>
    <td>{age}</td>
    <td>{mobile_no}</td>
    <td>{email_id}</td>
    <td>{refer_by}</td>
    <td>{test_request}</td>
    <td>{report_status}</td>
    <td>{total_amt}</td>
    <td>{receipt_amt}</td>
    <td>{bal_amt}</td>
    <td><Link to={`/edit/${r_id}`} r_id={r_id} className="btn-floating btn-large blue"><i class="large material-icons">edit</i></Link></td>
    <td><button className="btn-floating btn-large red"><i class="large material-icons">delete</i></button></td>
    </tr>             
</tbody>
   </table>
    </div>
)

export default connect()(Reportlistitem)
```

**this is my form where this error is occured**

```js
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {fetchReportsbyid} from '../actions/reports'

class ReportForm extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    state = {
        r_id:this.props.report ? this.props.report.r_id :0,
        reg_date:this.props.report ? this.props.report.reg_date :'',
        reg_no:this.props.report ? this.props.report.reg_no:'',
        patient_name:this.props.report ?  this.props.report.patient_name:'',
        gender:this.props.report ? this.props.report.gender:'',
        age:this.props.report ? this.props.report.age:'',
        mobile_no:this.props.report ?  this.props.report.mobile_no:'',
        email_id:this.props.report ?  this.props.report.email_id:'',    
        refer_by:this.props.report ?  this.props.report.refer_by:'',
        test_request:this.props.report ?  this.props.report.test_request:'',
        report_status:this.props.report ?  this.props.report.report_status:'',
        total_amt:this.props.report ?  this.props.report.total_amt:'',
        receipt_amt:this.props.report ?  this.props.report.receipt_amt:'',
        bal_amt:this.props.report ?  this.props.report.bal_amt:'' 
     }

     componentDidMount = () => {
        if(this.props.match.params.r_id){
            this.props.fetchReportsbyid(this.props.match.params.r_id)
        }
    }

     handleChange = (e) => {
         this.setState({[e.target.name]:e.target.value})
         console.log(this.state)
     }

     onSubmit = (e) => {
         e.preventDefault();
        this.props.onSubmit({
            reg_date:this.state.reg_date,
            reg_no:this.state.reg_no,
            patient_name:this.state.patient_name,
            gender:this.state.gender,
            age:this.state.age,
            mobile_no:this.state.mobile_no,
            email_id:this.state.email_id,    
            refer_by:this.state.refer_by,
            test_request:this.state.test_request,
            report_status:this.state.report_status,
            total_amt:this.state.total_amt,
            receipt_amt:this.state.receipt_amt,
            bal_amt:this.state.bal_amt,
            done:this.state.done
        })
     }
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="row">
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} className="col s12">
                    <div className="row">
                    <div className="input-field col s4">         
                    <input id="reg_date"  name="reg_date" type="date" className="validate" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="input-field col s4">
                    <input id="reg_no" name="reg_no" type="text" className="validate" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                    <label for="reg_no">Registration no</label>
                  </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row">
                    <div className="input-field col s4">         
                    <input id="patient_name" name="patient_name" type="text" className="validate" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    <label for="patient_name">Patient Name</label>
                    </div>
                    <div className="input-field col s4">
                    <input id="gender" name="gender" type="text" className="validate" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                    <label for="gender">Gender</label>
                  </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row">
                    <div className="input-field col s4">        
                    <input id="age" name="age" type="text" className="validate" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    <label for="age">Age</label>
                    </div>
                    <div className="input-field col s4">
                    <input id="refer_by" name="refer_by" type="text" className="validate" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                    <label for="refer_by">Refer by</label>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="row">
                  <div className="input-field col s4">        
                  <input id="mobile_no" name="mobile_no" type="text" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                  <label for="mobile_no">Mobile Number</label>
                  </div>
                  <div className="input-field col s4">
                  <input id="email_id" name="email_id" type="email" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                  <label for="email_id">Email Id</label>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row">
                    <div className="input-field col s4">        
                    <input id="test_rquest" name="test_request" type="text" className="validate" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                    <label for="test_rquest">Test Requested</label>
                    </div>
                    <div className="input-field col s4">
                    <input id="report_status" name="report_status" type="text" className="validate" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                    <label for="report_status">Report Status</label>
                  </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row">
                    <div className="input-field col s2">        
                    <input id="total_amt" name="total_amt" type="text" className="validate" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                    <label for="total_amt">Total Amount</label>
                    </div>
                    <div className="input-field col s2">
                    <input id="receipt_amt" name="receipt_amt" type="text" className="validate" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                    <label for="receipt_amt">Receipt Amount</label>
                  </div>
                  <div className="input-field col s2">
                  <input id="bal_amt" type="text" name="bal_amt" className="validate" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                  <label for="bal_amt">Balance Amount</label>
                </div>
                    </div>
                <div className="input-field col 26">
                <input type="submit" className="btn waves-effect waves-light" value="Save Report"/>
                </div>
                </form>
                    </div>
        )
    }
}

export default connect()(ReportForm)
```

please help he to figure it out whats the error here

my router file code is this whats the issue with this

```js
import React from 'react'
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Link,NavLink} from 'react-router-dom'
import Dashboard from '../components/reportdashboard'
import Createreport from '../components/addreport'
import Editreport from '../components/editreport'
import Notfound from '../components/notfound'
import Header from '../components/header'
import Footer from '../components/footer'


const AppRouter = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
    <Header />
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={ Dashboard } exact={true} />
        <Route path="/create" component={ Createreport } />
        <Route path="/edit/:r_id" component={ Editreport } />
        <Route component={ Notfound }/>
    </Switch>
    <Footer />
    </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
)

export default AppRouter
```

Comment: The error means `this.props.match` is undefined in the context of your `ReportForm` component. This usually means you failed/forgot to associate a Route to this component.

Comment: jaxx i have added `router file` code can you help to find out what's issue

Comment: I'm assuming your `ReportForm` component is used by both your `Createreport` and `Editreport` components, correct? At any rate, you can see that there is no route declaration directly corresponding to your `ReportForm` component, so you have 2 solutions. The simplest - and in my opinion the best - is to retrieve `this.props.match.params.r_id` in your `Editreport` component (where it will be available) and pass it as a prop to `ReportForm`. The (needlessly complicated) alternative is to wrap `ReportForm` with the `withRouter` HOC and use the HOC-provided interface to retrieve the parameter.

Comment: thanx jaxx may this work if not i will come back to you